# Scrapy a website that need use cookies

Tags: python, cookies, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm making  scrapy for scraping a website, but this website is working  with cookies ,I don't know How I can a make instruccion for scraping the data of website using the cookies

```
class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.HtmlXPathSelector('//ul[@class="directory-url"]/li')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['name'] = site.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['url'] = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

How I can add correctly cookies to this url

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @omair_77's answer, you can override the `start_requests` method of your spider to add cookies to the initial request by your Spider:

```
def start_requests(self):
    return [Request(url="http://www.example.com",
           cookies={'currency': 'USD', 'country': 'UY'})]
```

This way, the first request your spider will make is with those cookies, and the first call to your `parse` method will be with the response.

http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests

Answer (score 0):

You can add cookies like this

```
request_with_cookies = Request(url="http://www.example.com",
               cookies={'currency': 'USD', 'country': 'UY'})
```

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response

Comment: Thanks, I try this but I can´t iterate this request_with_cookies

Comment: can you please elaborate, what you mean by iterating?

Comment: With that request_wit_cookies I have not been able to get the items as I get to after the data with xpath